# Why can a multiplicative system not contain zero divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A multiplicative system $S$ is one where $1\in S$ and $a,b\in S\implies ab\in S$.

My book says that regular elements of a ring form a multiplicative system.

Why does every unital subring of the ring not form a multiplicative system? Why can a multiplicative system not have zero divisors? I don't see any contradictions here.

Comment: It might well have zero divisors. For example, $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is a multiplicative system and $[2]\cdot [2]=0$.

Comment: Are the statements in the final paragraph quoted from somewhere, or were they deduced by you? If the latter, then how did you deduce them?

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is a zero divisor in $S$ and if $b$ such that $a\cdot b =0$ and $b$ is in  $S$ then $0\in S$...

Other wise it need not be....

In case of $S = \{ [1], [2], [4] \}$ seen assubset of $\mathbb{Z}_6$, only element in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ that makes $[2]$ to be zero when multiplied by it is $[3]$ but $[3]\notin S$ so $[0]\notin S$

So, a multiplicative set can have zero divisors but not $0$ in it...

Answer (score 1):

The definition itself may not be problematic if zero-divisors are allowed. 
However, multiplicative systems $S\subseteq A$ ($A$ a ring with $1$) are intended to create "fractions" with elements of $S$ in the denominator, and I assume you can guess what happens if we allow anything remotely resembling zero in a denominator.
We want to work "as usual" with such fractions, i.e.

- We can identify $a = \frac a1$. For this we need $1\in S$
- $\frac {a_1}{s_1}\cdot \frac {a_2}{s_2}=\frac {a_1a_2}{s_1s_2}$. For this we need $a_1,a_2\in S\implies a_1a_2\in S$
- It would be nice to have $\frac {a_1}{s_1}= \frac {a_2}{s_2}\iff s_2a_1=s_1a_2$. but there are reasons why we need the mor general $\frac {a_1}{s_1}= \frac {a_2}{s_2}\iff \exists s\in S\colon ss_2a_1=ss_1a_2$. Nor for this it would be a desaster if we could pick $s=0$!

From the last item we see that we'd better require $0\notin S$ as one of the defining properties of multiplicative systems when trying to define fractions. From the multiplicative property this immediately gives us that $S$ cannot contain *nilpotent* elements. On the other hand, zero divisors are not immediately forbidden - as long as the corresponding co-divisors are not in $S$, i.e. whenever $ab=0$ then at most one of $a,b$ is $\in S$.

Answer (score 0):

A multiplicative system can contain zero divisors, it can also include two elements that multiply to $0$, as long as the system also contains the zero. For example, any ring is a multiplicative system.

Your example of regular elements is just one example (which does, of course, not contain zero divisors) of many.

Comment: Well, the multiplicative system $S = \{ [1], [2], [4] \}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ contains zero divisors, but it does not contain zero.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti : He should have been more specific... If $a$ is a zero divisor in $S$ and if $b$ such that $a\cdot b =0$ and $b$ is in  $S$ then $0\in S$...Other wise it need not be.... In case of $S = \{ [1], [2], [4] \}$ element $[3]$ makes $[2]$ to be zero but $[3]\notin S$ so $[0]\notin S$